# Story behind Vashishtha's curse to Vasus and Bhishma's birth

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma

I'm reading Kisari Mohan Ganguly's English translation of Mahabharata. In his translation,
in the Sambhava Up-Parva in Adi Parva, Chapters 96 and 99 tell 2 different stories of how Vasus became River Ganga's children and why Bhishma lived while other Vasus didn't have to live for long on Earth.

## **According to Chapter 96:**

***Reason behind Vasus getting cursed*** - Vasus to Ganga, ‘O queen of rivers, we have been cursed, for a venial fault, by the illustrious Vasishtha in anger. The foremost of excellent Rishis, Vasishtha, had been engaged in his twilight adorations and seated as he was, he could not be seen by us. We crossed him in ignorance. Therefore, in wrath he hath cursed us, saying, Be ye born among men!’

***Reason behind Bhishma bound to live a longer life on Earth than other Vasus*** -
Although Ganga agreed to be the mother of the Vasus, they asked her to throw the children after birth, into the water, so that they may be rescued soon without having to live on earth for any length of time. But Ganga said that she had to give Shantanu at least one son that lives, to which Vasus reply, ‘We shall each contribute an eighth part of our respective energies. With the sum thereof, thou shall have one son according to thy and his wishes.'

## **According to Chapter 99:**

***Reason behind Vasus getting cursed*** - Vasus and their wives were enjoying themselves in the forest when the wife of Dyu spotted an excellent cow and asked her husband to steal it. The cow was Nandini, daughter of Surabhi, and was owned by the sage Vashishtha. With the help of his brothers, Dyu stole Nandini. When Vasishtha realised what happened he cursed the Vasus to be born as mortals.

***Reason behind Bhishma bound to live a longer life on Earth than other Vasus*** -
Upon their pleading, Vashishta showed mercy and told the other seven Vasus that they will be liberated soon after their birth. However, Dyu being the protagonist of the theft was cursed to endure a longer life on the earth.

My question is why are there 2 different stories behind Vasus' (including Bhishma) birth on Earth. Is the translated version missing something or is there a reason behind the 2 different stories?